# Не получается добавить свое поле в UserIdentity

Tags: asp.net-core

Имеется
Проект `asp.net core 2.1` в который я добавил `area identity`, и `razor` страницы авторизации, регистрации, смены пароля подключил базу MySql etc. Все работало.
Проблема:
Дефолтные поля, которые были в миграции меня не устраивают (точнее не хватает) например поля `login`. Поле `login` я добавил на страницу `razor` (и в модель и в логику) после добавил в `БД`. Сделал в консоле пакетов `remove-migration` `add-migration` `update-database`. Добавил класс, унаследовав его `public class User: UserIdentity{}`. В классе объявил свойство `login`.

Ошибка:
1) A database operation failed while processing the request.
DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. 
MySqlException: Field 'Login' doesn't have a default value 
MySqlException: Field 'Login' doesn't have a default value 
2)There are pending model changes for ApplicationDbContext
In Visual Studio, use the Package Manager Console to scaffold a new migration for these changes and apply them to the database:

PM> Add-Migration [migration name]

PM> Update-Database
Alternatively, you can scaffold a new migration and apply it from a command prompt at your project directory:

`> dotnet ef migrations add [migration name]`

`> dotnet ef database update`

[image: Ошибка при попытке регистрации]

[image: Дерево проекта]

Comment: Поле Login наверняка not null. Либо сделайте его null, либо добавьте default value, либо (что правильнее) добавьте задание дефолтного значения в скрипт миграции.

Comment: Я думаю что ошибка в том, что в startup при инициализации identity указан класс UserIdentity, а надо User.

Comment: @Alexander Petrov я так делал, не помагает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял вопрос.

Я его расширяю так:

```
 public class User : IdentityUser
{

    [StringLength(30, MinimumLength = 2)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Name { get; set; }


    [StringLength(30, MinimumLength = 2)]
    [Display(Name = "Surname")]
    public string Surname { get; set; }


    [StringLength(30, MinimumLength = 2)]
    [Display(Name = "Midl Name")]
    public string Midlname { get; set; }

    public string Obligation { get; set; }
}
```

Затем подключаю к контексту

```
 public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<User>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
       : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<User> User { get; set; }

}
```

В стартапе ничего не переопределяю и не трогаю. Этого достаточно

Таким образом я добавил к полям по умолчанию свои поля. их можно добавить склько хош.

Comment: Это я и сам понял ) Ошибка была в том, что я не менял стандартный useridentity в генерируемых представлениях `razor` и в файле `startup`

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду, что б использовать данную модель на фронте вы переопределяли ее(UserIdentity) в стартапе?

Comment: Не переопределять, а просто задаю начальные настройки (там нужно указать класс)

Comment: Ну в таком случаи я б вам вообще рекомендовал бы использовать отдельные моделе для страницы например UserViewModel. Там какие угодно поля делайте, затащивайте в контроллер на бекенд а записывайте в таблицу уже через User, так которая подключена к контексту, даже если вы ее расширили как я в примере показал, то не нужно уже в стартапе указывать начальные строки и тд.